# How to display @

Tags: android, xml

How to display @
i want to display & so i did & it work fine but i didn' know how to display @

```
  <string name="feedbackname">nom &amp; prenom</string>
<string name="feedbackemail"> @ email</string>
```

didn't work it display xml error

Answer (score 2):

You should use the "\" before "@". eg

```
<string name="google mail">\@gmail.com</string>
```

Refer to this [link](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2219) it's very useful

Answer (score 0):

`@` does not require escaping in XML. You could try `&#64;`, but you shouldn't need to.

These, however, do require escaping:

```
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
'   &apos;
"   &quot;
```

Please provide more details about your XML parser and the actual error message that it is throwing.

Comment: K_Anas is right... check the link he posted.  It is very informative.